# Uploaded images not publicly readable

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Im unable to see images by the URL returned from getPublicUrl(). The image is uploaded directly to `Google Cloud Storage` via `HTTP POST` and I can see them in Datastore/Blobstore Viewer on `http://localhost:8000`.

```
try{
     echo CloudStorageTools::getPublicUrl("gs://qbucket_first/sample.jpeg", true);
   }catch ( CloudStorageException $e ) {
      echo 'There was an exception creating the Image Public URL, details ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

What I get is this: `http://localhost:8080/_ah/gcs/qbucket_first/sample.jpeg` But I receive a 404 error when entering that URL. How can I fix this problem? I am using Chrome, Mac OS X, GAELauncher v1.8.9 PHP.

#### Edit 1

If I run this code:

```
file_put_contents("gs://qbucket_first/hello.txt", "Hello");
echo CloudStorageTools::getPublicUrl("gs://qbucket_first/hello.txt", true);
```

I get

```
http://localhost:8080/_ah/gcs/qbucket_first/hello.txt
```

And when entering this URL, I can download the file and read the content. So it works with text files which means that Datastore is working on local dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using the dev server, which seems to be the problem. Run it from production.

Comment: I don't think that dev server is causing it. See Edit 1 for more info.

Comment: Try on production. You are using dev

Comment: Tried on production now. Works fine with getImageServingUrl() but not with getPublicUrl(). Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

There's the same thing in Python version Google App Engine.

dev_appserver.py create a fake Cloud Storage for local development, when you write something into Google Cloud Storage in local environment, it actually writes it into a fake space, `getPublicUrl()` in local environment only gets the fake url in your local Google Cloud Storage.

The first time you upload the file to the real Google Cloud Storage, so in the local environment you get 404.

the second time you save the file in your local runtime, so it actually writes into the local fake GCS environment, so the second time it works.

Answer (score 0):

Does the image filename have spaces?
If yes, remove the spaces or replace with _.